# Populating ArrayList from text file with different variable types

Tags: java, arraylist

Im working on a project that requires me to load a number of courses for a university. Each course is made up of a Course name(ex. "CSCI 150" , "CSCI 150L") and a section number(ex "CSCI 150 1", "CSCI 150L 1").

I am trying to load an arrayList with these courses but everytime I try to display them afterwards, I get an input mismatch exception or a Nosuchelement exception

Here is what my code looks like with the text file im using to test it underneath.

```
public class Prog6 {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws FileNotFoundException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    School university = new School();
    File aFile = new File("prog6.txt");
    Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(aFile);
    String courseName;
    int section;
    int numberEnrolled;

    while(fileReader.hasNextLine()){
        courseName = fileReader.next() + fileReader.next();
        section = fileReader.nextInt();
        Course aCourse = new Course(courseName, section);
        university.addCourse(aCourse);
    }

    university.displayCourses();



}
```

}

Text file looks exactly like this:

```
CSCI 150 1
CSCI 150 2
CSCI 150L 1
CSCI 140 1
MATH 174 1
MATH 132 2
MATH 412L 1
MATH 174 2
BIOL 110 1
BIOL 210 1
CBAD 310L 1
CBAD 110 1
CBAD 210 2
```

Comment: I'd advice to read a whole line (`nextLine()`), then split it on spaces. This way, your program can account for faulty text files that deviate from the expected format.

Comment: Also, you're describing an `ArrayList` and that the problems comes from the `displayCourses()` method, yet you don't show us neither the `ArrayList` nor that method.

Comment: i know the displayCourses() method works, im just calling it to test that my arraylist is populated from the file. The issue is getting the values from the file to properly store since there are different variable types on the same line and some of the courses have a 150L or 140L which is an int with a string at the end which confuses me.

Comment: Well, the code works flawlessly once you remove everything related to `School` and `Course`, so the error has to be within one of those. And you said yourself *"everytime I try to display them afterwards, I get an input mismatch exception or a Nosuchelement exception"* - I don't think anyone will be able to help if you don't actually show us the relevant pieces of code.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't compile it, may have some minor syntax error, but this should do the trick.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prog6 {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws FileNotFoundException 
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        School university = new School();
        File aFile = new File("prog6.txt");
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(aFile);
        String courseName;
        int section = -1;
        int numberEnrolled;
        String currentLine = "";
        String regex = "(\\S+)(\\s)(\\S+)(\\s)(\\d)";
        Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher;
        while(fileReader.hasNextLine()){
            courseName = "";
            currentLine = fileReader.nextLine();
            try {
                matcher = regexPattern.match(currentLine);
                matcher.find();
                courseName = matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(3);
                section = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(5));
            }   catch   (Exception e)   {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            Course aCourse = new Course(courseName, section);
            university.addCourse(aCourse);
        }
        university.displayCourses();
        fileReader.close();
    }
}
```